# Ubuntu Installation Alongside Windows

Tags: system-installation

I am new to Ubuntu and I have  recently burned an Ubuntu .iso file on to a DVD and booted in to Ubuntu.

My disk is 80GiB and it is already partitioned in 2 parts. C: where the Windows is installed, this is 65GiB, and the second partition is 15GiB.

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 and preferably in the second partition (15gb).
Which option should I choose? "Install alongside Windows." or The Manual install or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You should choose `something else`.

The `along side` option, creates space from C: drive and install it there. If you try to do so now, it will take space from 64gb partition. Not the 15GB.

After choosing `something else`, do the following,

- In the window, identify the 15gb partition. it should be marked as `sda2`
- Select it in the list, click on `Delete`.
- Then, click on `New`, select file system as `SWAP` from the dropdown list, (partition type `logical` or `primary` doesn't matter as 4 primary partition can be there)  give size around 1GB/2GB as swap space. If you have 1GB ram, I suggest 2GB as swap space. Click `OK`
- Now, click on the remaining space (13GB), select file system as  `ext4` , mounting point **`/`** (root symbol). Click `ok`
- Make sure `booloader location` is pointing to your correct disk `sda`
- Now proceed with installation.

Good luck.